# ImportError with Numpy but Docker build works

Tags: python

Very recently I've been getting `ImportError`s when running a Python script. The script (`graph.py`) lives within a Flask app that I have Dockerized.

When I was running `python webtools/tools/graph.py` (full file dir below) I would get this error:
`AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'random'`
at the line where I import `pandas` (`import pandas as pd`).

When I run Python interactively, I can run `import pandas` just fine -- as well as `import numpy` -- EXCEPT after I `cd` into `webtools/tools`. When I'm in that directory and run Python interactively, I get an error with `import pandas` and `import numpy`:

```
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: cannot import name randbits
```

and

```
ImportError: cannot import name randbits
```

I currently have following package versions installed:

```
numpy==1.23.2
pandas==1.4.3
conda version : 4.12.0
conda-build version : 3.21.8
python version : 3.9.12.final.0
```

I don't understand why this package error occurs depending on what my current directory is. I'm also wondering if the fact that I installed the packages via `pip` while running in Anaconda has something to do with it.

Recap:

- No issue importing `numpy` from other working directories
- No issues building Docker image and running container

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── __pycache__
├── atlantis.yaml
├── dist
│   └── ...
├── webtools
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── lib
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tools  ### Doesn't work when I've cd into here
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── apollo-272319-1425111bd2ab.json
│   │   ├── graph.py
│   │   ├── map_params.yml
│   │   └── secrets.py
│   └── views.py
├── webtools.egg-info
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── terraform
└── tests
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It's because I had a file named `secrets.py` in the `tools` folder. I renamed it and I can import `numpy` again.